# Why std::declval<int>() = std::declval<int>() is invalid?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, built-in-types

I'm trying to use `detector` I wrote which according to [std::experiment::is_detected_v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) to check whether a type is assignable.  However `std::declval<int>() = std::declval<int>()` is invalid and only `std::declval<int&>() = std::declval<int>()` is valid.

Why does this happen?

Comment: When you say `detector` do you mean https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected ?

Comment: @John Zwinck That's sth I wrote according to it.

Comment: Because you need an Lvalue on the Left side of `=`.

Comment: @o11c But it seems ```int{} = int{}``` is valid.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu Nope, that fails for me. Note that classes are different than primitives.

Comment: @o11c Oh yes, there seem to be some problem with the online compiler I use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the signature of [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

```
template<class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

`std::declval<int>()` has type `int&&`, an rvalue(xvalue). You can't assign to an rvalue `int`.